# How to supress a subreport if it has no data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

The solution below was posted by user Brian for how to suppress empty subreport in SSRS2008. The answer is to place the subreport into a rectangle. Then set the visibility of the rectangle to something like this:

```
=IIF(First(Fields![SOMEFEILD].Value, "[SOMEDATASET]") IS NOTHING, TRUE, FALSE)
```

I tried the recommended expression but it didn't work. The expression doesn’t make sense because I didn't think a rectangle has fields that make up a dataset instead it's an object. So how would I reference a field value in the rectangle like in the expression sample? For me, what would `[SOMEDATASET]` be?

Note: I placed the subreport into a rectangle. The subreport has a dataset called DataSet1 with three fields in it.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset in your main report should query the same data as the one in the subreport. To keep things DRY you could use a View or Stored Procedure as a basis for both reports. To keep things nice performance-wise your main report's DataSet could get away with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vw_SomeViewForSubreport
```

Then use this in the subreport:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM vw_SomeViewForSubreport
```

Comment: That's okay, you can add a *second* dataset for the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query to determine whether the subreport should be shown.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. So for my second dataset for the subreport, my query would be Select count(*) from DataSet1? Note: DataSet1 is the name of the dataset in my subreport. Correct? If not, then after the from would it be the name of the SQL stored procedure? Thanks for your help, Ting